# Почему свойство-объект пребразуется к строковому типу?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект у него есть свойство объявленного как объект, но при обращению к нему оказывается что это свойство имеет тип строка. В чем причина такого преобразования?

Вот код:

```
<script>
    var test = new Object();
    test.property1 = 1;
    test.property2 = "1";
    test.property3 = new Object();
    test.property3.property1 = 1;
    test.property3.property2 = "1";

    for (var name in test){
        document.write(name + " type: " + typeof name + "<br>");
    }
</script>
```

результат:

```
property1 type: string
property2 type: string
property3 type: string // не ясно почему это строковый тип, а не объект?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому, что `for (var name in test){}` перебирает ключи объекта, а не значения свойств. В таком цикле, любой ключ будет является строкой, соответственно и `typeof key` вернет строку.

Чтобы перебрать значения свойств, необходимо в цикле использовать (в Вашем случае) `typeof test[name]`.

Comment: Я бы перефразировал: ключ (имя свойства) в цикле [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) **всегда** является строкой.